# Finding all ocurrences from determinate word and exctracting the next word in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a .txt file where the word 'picture:' is found multiple times in the file. How can I extract all words after the 'pictures:' word and save in a text file

I tried the follow code,but doesn't work:

```
cat users_sl.txt |awk -F: '/^login:"/{print $2}' cookies.txt
```

`user_sl.txt`:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis picture lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis. Quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Turpis massa sed elementum  picture tempus egestas. Condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant. Et molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper. Tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu  picture dictum varius. Donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed. Tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est. Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu. Mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis`

picturelist.txt:

```
lobortis
dictum
tempus
```

Comment: You can't have both a file awk parameter and use STDIN at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm assuming you actually just have `picture` instead of `**picture:**`, and that you may need to deal with line breaks, so...

```
$ cat sl.txt 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Quis picture lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam.
Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis.
Quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed.
Turpis massa sed elementum picture tempus egestas.
Condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant.
Et molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper.
Tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu picture
dictum varius. Donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed.
Tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est.
Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu.
Mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis

$ cat sl.txt | tr '\n' ' ' | grep -o 'picture [^ ]*' | cut -d' ' -f2
lobortis
tempus
dictum
```

Edit: Explanation:

`tr '\n' ' '` replaces every (unix) line break with a space -- makes the whole thing one line.

The `-o` flag tells `grep` to return only the matched string.  The search pattern starts with picture and a space `picture` , and then everything that follows that is not a space: `[^ ]*`.

Finally `cut` using the space character for a delimiter `-d ' '` prints the second field: `-f 2`

Comment: Useless use of cat. tr can read file on his own

Comment: @GillesQuenot Not in RHEL.

Comment: Thanks for lot.  By the way,  can you explains me this  code step by step,  please?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bash solution with a clean shellcheck. Tested with bash version 5.2.2 on a MacOS Ventura system.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFS=" " read -r -a WORDS <<< "$(tr '\n' ' ' < users_sl.txt)"

echo processing ${#WORDS[@]} words

for (( i=0; i < ${#WORDS[@]}; i++ ))
do
    if [ "${WORDS[$i]}" = "picture" ]; then
        echo "${WORDS[i+1]}"
    fi
done | tee picturelist.txt
```

Comment: edited to match the posed problem using the files

Answer (score 0):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
$ perl -nE 'say for /\bpicture\b\s+(\w+)\b/g' user_sl.txt | tee picturelist.txt
lobortis
tempus
dictum
```

Answer (score 0):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
$ awk '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i == "picture") print $(i+1)
    }
}' user_sl.txt | tee picturelist.txt
```

or

```
$ printf '%s\n' $(< users_sl.txt) |
    awk '/picture/{p=1;next} {if (p==1) {print;p=0}}' > picturelist.txt
```

```
lobortis
tempus
dictum
```

Answer (score 0):

With [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=( $(<user_sl.txt) )
for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++)); do
    if [[ ${arr[i]} == picture ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "${arr[i+1]}"
    fi
done | tee picturelist.txt
```

### Output

```
lobortis
tempus
dictum
```